# Why doesn't git-diff --raw on OS X show stat-only changes?

Tags: git, git-diff

I have been looking at stat-only changes with git.  The following works on Ubuntu but not OS X:

```
$ git init
$ echo 123 > README
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Initial'
[master (root-commit) f38a08f] Initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ touch README
$ git -c 'diff.autorefreshindex=0' diff -- README
$ git -c 'diff.autorefreshindex=0' diff --raw -- README
:100644 100644 190a180... 0000000... M  README
```

On OS X the final git command doesn't show any output.  Why not?

I'm using git v2.6.4 on OS X 10.11.2 (and git 1.7.9.5 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS).

Comment: on OSX, do `ls -l README` ; then `touch README`; and again `ls -l README`. Do the outputs differ?

Comment: oh and what are your git versions on both machines? use `git --version`

Comment: Yes, the outputs differ.  Git versions are at the end of my question.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a bug in git version 1.7.9.5. If `git diff` doesn't show anything; `git diff --raw` isn't supposed to either in my opinion. In the [git documentation for version 1.7.9.5](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff/1.7.9.5) it says:

> M: modification of the contents or mode of a file

so in my opinion; changing the modification time (using `touch`) shouldn't show up in git at all..

Comment: I get the same lack of output with git 2.7.0 on OS X 10.11.2.  I'm looking at stat (file access/modification time) changes, not mode changes.  The docs for `diff.autorefreshindex` state that when it's false, a stat-only change counts as a change.

Comment: It is strange that you still get the difference with very similar git versions. In the doc: ` Note that this affects only 'git diff' Porcelain, and not lower level 'diff' commands such as 'git diff-files'.`